# Hide Element in React Based on Routing

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I wanted to hide the `RightMenu` if the routes are `/jobs` and `/account`.
My problem is that if `/jobs` and `/account` have children routes like `/jobs/1` or `/accounts/2`. How would i include it? Is there way to hide this? Is there a better way than my code?

**UPDATE**

What about if we wanted to show the `RightMenu` on `/jobs/new` BUT not on `/jobs/1`? Something like that.

Pls check my codesandbox here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/sidenav-rypco?file=/src/pages/PagesRoute.js)

```
const noRightMenusRoutes = ["/jobs", "/account"];

  const noRightMenus = () => {
    return (
      noRightMenusRoutes.findIndex((el) => el.includes(location.pathname)) !==
      -1
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a state that will be updated when the path name changes :

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy, useState, useEffect } from "react";
....

function PagesRoute({ match: { url } }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(true);
  const [noRightMenusRoutes, setNoRightMenusRoutes] = useState([
    "/jobs",
    "/account"
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.pathname);
    const noRightMenus = noRightMenusRoutes.findIndex((el) => {
      return location.pathname.includes(el);
    });

    setShowMenu(noRightMenus === -1);
  }, [location, noRightMenusRoutes]);

  ...

 <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={3}>
                {!showMenu ? null : <RightMenu />}
 </Grid>
```

[image: Edit Sidenav (forked)]

You shouldn't use functions inside the JSX for rendering purposes, the functions could be used as event handlers.

Comment: Thank you. What about if we wanted to show the `RightMenu` on `/jobs/new` BUT not on `/jobs/1`?  Something like that.... Can you two separate functions that will be integrated to one so it will be easier if we have many routes? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

React router's [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath) function is a really handy utility to handle these things
You can do something like this

```js
const noRightMenusRoutes = ["/jobs", "/account"];
const isMatching = noRightMenusRoutes.some(path => {
    const match = matchPath(location.pathname, {
      path: path,
      exact: true
    })
    return match && match.isExact
})
```

Using this will also help you with paths with parameters such as `/jobs/:jobId`